# Is there a way to set the value of an array using graphic buttons in java?

Tags: java, arrays, button, draw

Im trying to set value to an array according to which buttons are pressed (the array is [4])

I've tried a loop with for and to use the ActionListener but it just return 4 times the first value, and I want to set it to 4 different value

```java
package stackOverflow;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class mainStack extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton jbr,jbv,jbb,jbo,jbn,jbj; 
    JTextField l11b;
    String a;
        mainStack(){

            this.setLayout(null);
            jbr = new JButton("Rouge");
            jbr.setBounds(0,80,85,30);
            add(jbr);

            jbv = new JButton("Vert");
            jbv.setBounds(125, 80, 85, 30);
            add(jbv);

            jbb = new JButton("Bleu");
            jbb.setBounds(0, 120, 85, 30);
            add(jbb);

            jbj = new JButton("Jaune");
            jbj.setBounds(125, 120, 85, 30);
            add(jbj);

            jbo = new JButton("Orange");
            jbo.setBounds(0, 160, 85,30);
            add(jbo);

            jbn = new JButton("Noir");
            jbn.setBounds(125,160, 85,30);
            add(jbn);

            jbr.addActionListener(this);
            jbv.addActionListener(this);
            jbb.addActionListener(this);
            jbj.addActionListener(this);
            jbo.addActionListener(this);
            jbn.addActionListener(this);

            setLayout(null);
            setSize(800,800);
            setVisible(true);
        }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int i,b = 0;
                int tabAnswer[]= new int [4];
                for(i=0;i<tabAnswer.length;i++) {
                    if(e.getSource().equals(jbr)) {
                        a ="R";
                    }
                    else if(e.getSource().equals(jbv)) {
                        a = "V";
                    }
                    else if(e.getSource().equals(jbj)) {
                        a = "J";
                    }
                    else if(e.getSource().equals(jbb)) {
                        a = "B";
                    }
                    else if(e.getSource().equals(jbo)) {
                        a = "O";
                    }
                    else if(e.getSource().equals(jbn)) {
                        a = "N";
                    }
                    else { }
                    if(a.contentEquals("R")) {
                        b=0;
                    }
                    if(a.contentEquals("V")) {
                        b=1;
                    }
                    if(a.contentEquals("J")) {
                        b=2;
                    }
                    if(a.contentEquals("B")){
                        b=3;
                    }
                    if(a.contentEquals("O")) {
                        b=4;
                    }
                    if(a.contentEquals("N")) {
                        b=5;
                    }
                    tabAnswer[i]=b;

                }
                for(i=0;i<tabAnswer.length;i++) {

                    System.out.println(tabAnswer[i]);
                }

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainStack t= new mainStack();

    }
}
```

I want it to wait for me to press the button 4 time, to display the 4 value of this array, but instead it only displays one

EDIT: As you can see my array takes only one value out of the six possible. I would like to be able to set it to {0,1,2,3} for example using the buttons. I hope this is better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extract `tabAnswer` and an `index` to fields. Each time a button is pressed set the current `index` in your array and increment the `index`. If the array is full (`index >= tabAnswer.length`) print the array or do what ever you want to do with it. Optionally reset the index to prevent an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Here is an example:

```
private int index = 0;
private int[] tabAnswer = new int[4];

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(jbr)) {
        tabAnswer[index] = 0;
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(jbv)) {
        tabAnswer[index] = 1;
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(jbj)) {
        tabAnswer[index] = 2;
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(jbb)) {
        tabAnswer[index] = 3;
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(jbo)) {
        tabAnswer[index] = 4;
    } else if (e.getSource().equals(jbn)) {
        tabAnswer[index] = 5;
    }
    index++;
    if (index >= tabAnswer.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tabAnswer));
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible in additon of all that to extract the tabAnswer and display it in a Jtextfield ?

Comment: @GéraudDelPino Yes, of course. Just use `textField.setText()` instead of `System.out.println()`.